# Generating a data set for a simulation study

Tags: r, plot, simulation, estimation

This pic is from the [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1337268213) by Shao and Deng.

[image]

Here [image] and Q is from the singular value decomposition of X: [image]

I want to reproduce the data set based on these instructions. Here is the `R` code that I have written.

```
sigma = 10
n = 30 # 100 200
p = 100 # 500 2000 # increasing n/p
Sigma = matrix(0.75, p, p); diag(Sigma) = 1
beta = c(1 + 0.1*(1:20), rep(0, p - 20))
epsilon = rnorm(n, 0, sigma)
X = MASS::mvrnorm(n, rep(0, p), Sigma)
y = X%*%beta + epsilon

Q = svd(X)$v
theta = Q%*%t(Q)%*%beta
thetasq.sort = sort(theta^2)
L2.cpp = cumsum(thetasq.sort)/sum(theta^2)

plot(L2.cpp)
```

These are the plots: 1 (My plot) 2 (from the paper)

[image]

What is the reason for the difference?